# Extract circuit from schematic image

Tags: computer-vision

For my circuits homework, I like to use [circuit lab](https://www.circuitlab.com/) (the same service that [electrical engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) uses) to verify my work, but manually entering the circuits can be painful when they become large like this:

[image]

I noticed a [similar question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/66432/any-research-to-turn-schematics-as-a-picture-into-a-simulation) on EE which wasn't well received, but that user seemed to be looking to use integrated circuits. The top answer to the question said that such a tool (for integrated circuits) was impossible:

> Such a tool would be difficult to create, and impossible to realistically support considering the multitude of ways even a single IC could be represented

For the circuits I'm familiar with (non-integrated circuits like the above), I don't see why this would be impossible.

The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_symbol) on electronic symbols states that there are several standards for electronic symbols:

> - IEC 60617 (also known as British Standard BS 3939)
> - IEEE Std 91/91a
> - ANSI standard Y32 (also known as IEEE Std 315)
> - Australian Standard AS 1102

I wouldn't expect this software to be able to work with symbols that don't exactly match the symbols defined in those standards. For example, the software wouldn't need to recognize a human drawing, and the software wouldn't need to recognize a computer-generated schematic which used symbols not defined in the above standards.

The software could extract the circuit into any other format. Preferably, something like JSON, XML, etc. so that it could be used with APIs for solving circuits, etc.

An example JSON response might look something like:

```
{
  "resistors": [
    {
      "name": "R1",
      "positive": "N1",
      "negative": "N3",
      "ohms": 10
    },
    {
      "name": "R2",
      "positive": "N1",
      "negative": "N2",
      "ohms": 20
    },
    {
      "name": "R3",
      "positive": "N2",
      "negative": "N3",
      "ohms": 50
    }
  ],
  "nodes": [
    "N1",
    "N2"
  ],
  "current_sources": [
    {
      "name": "I1",
      "in": "N1",
      "out": "N3",
      "amps": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "I2",
      "in": "N3",
      "out": "N2",
      "amps": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there a piece of software which will take an image of a circuit which contains only symbols defined in the standards I've listed, that can extract the nodes and circuit elements into a textual format such as XML or JSON?

Comment: What operating system should it run on?

Comment: @Undo the operating system doesn't matter

Comment: @michaelsnoden: If entering that small a circuit is painful to you, consider learning the tool better. That's a pretty small circuit.